# How to add a class to td tag in bootstrap table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used below jquery code for my bootstrap table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table>tr>td').addClass('redBg');
    console.log('hg');    
});
```

As well as i tried this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table>tbody>tr>td').addClass('redBg');
    console.log('hg');

});
```

But the class will not added to the `td` tag,

Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/udarazz/0vx7tjfq/

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: how about  `$('.table tr > td').addClass('redBg')`

Comment: @N.Ivanov yes it's working, but i need to specify the table. Is there any other way to do that

Comment: when using jquery you do not need to use `.` infront of html defined tags. you can use `.` only with classnames

Comment: @N.Ivanov The table has a class called `table`, if you look inside the snippet

Comment: @Udara Try to use $(".table tr:eq(1) > td").addClass("redBg");

Comment: it's never wise to name classes with the same names as the predefined HTML tags

Comment: @Hamzaouiii you can raise this issue with Bootstrap developers. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit it, many browsers will implicitly add a `<tbody>` container to wrap all table rows. You can verify it by using your browser's developer tools/inspector. The resulting structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It means `<tr>` is no longer a direct child of `<table>`, and your `table > tr` selector won't work anymore.

To work around it, you can either:

- Explicitly include `<tbody>` in your markup and use `table > tbody > tr > td` selector.
- Don't use direct child selector: `table tr > td`

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vx7tjfq/7/).

As Bootstrap styles the backgrounds of even rows and hovers, you might need to make your class definition more specific than Bootstrap's built-in styles:

```
table.table tr > td.redBg {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Alternatively, you can add `!important` to your CSS to override:

```
.redBg {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table tr > td').addClass('redBg');
    console.log('hg');
});
```

Comment: Presumably the OP put the descendant selectors there for a reason. Removing them will change the logic for the styles applies

Answer (score 0):

If its the first `<td>` in the `<table>` you're trying to add the class to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table tr td:first-child').addClass('redBg');
  console.log('hg');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0vx7tjfq/5/