# Adding css class on click won't apply on all rows - Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm adding an a css class which should colour row which is currently clicked,
and I realized that it's working on every second row,
on first row it wont work, on second row it will work an so on, I cant understand why is that happening?

I must say also that I'm using bootstrap table on my view, and table rows are dynamically created, but all of them should be the same.

Here is how my table looks after rows are added:

[image]

I noticed by default  that rows are colour differently, that's how bootstrap table works I guess

And this is what is happened when I selected second row, it looks like this:

[image]

But when I'm clicking on a row 1 and on a row 3 nothing is happening even if I can see when I'm inspecting page that class is applied to row that I'm selecting.

My js:

```
$('#TableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('lol').siblings().removeClass('lol');
});
```

My css:

```
.lol
{
    background: gray;
}
```

Comment: provide your html maybe?

Comment: `.lol
{
    background: gray !important;
}`  try this once

Comment: Please post the markup as well and if possible using snippets create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Don't start fixing an issue with `!important` that just leads to more issues further on. IMHO - CSS quickly ends up with every single line being marked as `!important`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a class to td tag in bootstrap table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689657/how-to-add-a-class-to-td-tag-in-bootstrap-table-using-jquery)

Comment: I have to agree with Fran, the !important rule should only ever be applied minimally and designed to integrate with the rest of the stylesheet i.e. you need to plan when to use it and make note of where its been used. Bottom line, avoid using it if possible

Comment: Use chrome inspector to find out why that row isn't getting the style. It might be that another style is taking precedence.

Comment: In this case `!important` is not going to harm anything, because it's only available on click. Usually there is no class like `lol` will going to exist, and also after something happen when page refreshed every-thing will gone. I agreed that it's not a best practice, but in this case it will be ok.

Comment: The actual solution is change css by using parent table class selector as suggested in the link given  by @DarthJDG

Comment: Zakaria Acharki check the link itself.the row which have color already is not getting new color

Comment: @Roxy'Pro provide a snippet with your html please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37291/).**

You could attach the class to the `td`'s instead and make CSS more specific rule to override the one already applied.

**CSS:**

```
#TableItems>tbody>tr>td.lol
{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**JS :**

```
$('#TableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
  $('td',this).addClass('lol');
  $(this).siblings().find('td').removeClass('lol');
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#TableItems').on('click', 'td', function (e) {
  $('td').siblings().addClass('lol');
  $(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('td').removeClass('lol');
  
  console.log($(this).prop('id'));
});
```

```css
#TableItems>tbody>tr>td.lol
{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table id="TableItems" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="id_1">test id 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="id_2">test id 2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you move the jquery.js script reference above the bootstrap.js reference in your snippet it will get rid of that script error in your example.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki It works, but can you explain little bit why this example works and my example did not work?

Comment: Since the rule the must specific have the max priority against the less specific in CSS rules, your rule target any element with `lol` class when Bootstrap has already more specific rule that target the `td` and change his color `.table-hover>tbody>tr>td`.. To override it you should make a rule that is more specific as my answer provide.. That why

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thanks man,and in case each of this rows and `td` has some id, why can't I access it by `$(this).data('id');` ?

Comment: You're welcome, Should be retrieved using `$(this).attr('id');` or `$(this).prop('id');`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki `$(this).attr('id');` will actually get id from the row - `tr` ? and what about id from the `td`?

Comment: Updated my answer @Roxy'Pro

Answer (score 0):

If you **absolutely have to** use the `!important` rule to override any currently applied styles, for example on the bootstrap `.table-striped` class. Consider creating a list of classes that perform dedicated styling functions and are named appropriately to make sure its entirely obvious what they do.

The example below has renamed your `.lol` class to `.greyBackground_OVERRIDE` this indicates that you have overriden any previous values that existed on the element.

> Please be aware that if you do not keep track of where you use the `!Important rule` it can cause serious styling issues later down the line.

```js
$('#TableItems').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('greyBackground_OVERRIDE').siblings().removeClass('greyBackground_OVERRIDE');
});
```

```css
/*
  I recommend using the _OVERRIDE naming convention for these type of classes
*/
.greyBackground_OVERRIDE
{
  /* 
    makes use of the !important rule which gives this style preference over any others. 
  */
  background: grey !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-striped" id="TableItems">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> test </th>
      <th> test 2 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 3 </td>
      <td> 4 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 5 </td>
      <td> 6 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 7 </td>
      <td> 8 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 9 </td>
      <td> 10 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS should be:

```
        $('#TableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
            $(this).parent().find('tr').removeClass('lol');
            $(this).addClass('lol');
        });
```